# I have a variable and an matrix and how to move the elements right?

Tags: c++, matrix, shift

I have a matrix which is 3*3 for example, and I have a variable = 10.
This variable represents the first element of the new array. I need to store the last element as well in a new variable.
I need to move the matrix left to right, right to left, up to down, and down to up, by shifting the elements and getting the last element.
For example the default matrix:

```
[[0,1,2]
[3,4,5]
[6,7,8]]
```

Shifting the the first row with variable=5

```
[[5,0,1]
[3,4,5]
[6,7,8]]
```

and then I get back 2 the second result.
Another example shift from up to down the last column with variable=6:

```
[[5,0,6]
[3,4,2]
[6,7,5]]
```

and then I get back 8.

Here is a snippet of my c++ code, but I can accept every language.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int ar[3][3] = {  
   {0, 1, 2} ,   
   {3, 4, 5} ,   
   {6, 7, 8}   
};
    
    int x=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int temp = x[i];
        x[i]=x[i+1];
        x[i]=tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what you are trying to do. For example I do not see where the value 10 is used .

Comment: variable = 10 is used for the new first new element

Answer (score 0):

We can generalize the directions in such a manner that the same code would handle all of the cases. The example below is a proof-of-concept, yet, it was not actually tested, because I lack a C++ env at the moment. But, if it turns out to be some problem with it, then it should be fairly easy to fix it, so if it does not work yet, then please provide example inputs and outputs.

```
int index = 0; //It can be something between 0 and 2
int isRow = 1; //It can be 1 if it's a row to be shifted and 0 if it's a column to be shifted
int direction = 1; //It can be -1 if it's to the left/up (depending on the value of isRow) and 1 if it's right/down
int output; //The element we need to store at the end
int input = 10; // The element we need to append
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (i == 0) output = ar[isRow ? index : (2 - (direction + 1) + direction * i)][isRow ? (2 - (direction + 1) + (direction * i)) : index];
    else ar[isRow ? index : (2 - (direction + 1) + direction * i)][isRow ? (2 - (direction + 1) + (direction * (i - 1))) = ar[isRow ? index : (2 - (direction + 1) + direction * i)][isRow ? (2 - (direction + 1) + (direction * (i - 1)));
}
```